# Is there a difference between soft links and symbolic links?

Tags: linux, symlink, ln

On many websites, even on the Wikipedia article discussing links, I often see something like the following:

> Soft links (symbolic links)...

Why two names?

Is there a difference (currently or historically)?

---

Please read the question carefully and note that this is **not** about the difference between *hard* links and symbolic links, but on the terminology of *soft* links vs symbolic links

Comment: The documentation for `ln` only uses the terms hard link and symbolic link.

Comment: @0stone0 no, that question is about hard links vs symbolic links. While an answer mentions soft links as an "AKA", there is no explanation of why soft links are "AKA" symbolic links.

Comment: @stark good point, is there then a reason for why so much other documentation uses the "soft" terminology then?
This does not explain the use of "hard" as a differentiator, rather than saying "non-symbolic" or some other more directly relatable term

Comment: I feel like the name soft link is just for a dichotomy of hard vs soft link, but I have no references on the actual origin of the names